# Debian Install PHP with pcntl support

Tags: php, debian

I have been trying to compile php with pcntl support without luck. I have tried following several tutorials, but none of them helped.

My website is currently "live" and I cannot afford much down time. I want to get this done right the first time.

Thanks to all.

Comment: The package description for `php5-cli` in lenny indicates that it has pcntl support built in.  Any reason you're not using this one?

Comment: I thought I had to recompile php5, but later found out only pcntl needed to be compiled. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else with the same question:

don't recompile php5, only compile pcntl for your php version and move it to the php extension folder.